# Write tfrecords from beam pipeline?

Tags: java, tensorflow, apache-beam, tfrecord

I have some data in Map format and I want to convert them to tfrecords, using the beam pipeline.
Here is my attempt to write the code. I have attempted this in python which works but I need to implement this in java as some business logic is there which I can't port to python. The corresponding working python implementation can be found here in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61247661/writing-tfrecords-in-apche-beam-with-java).

```
import com.google.protobuf.ByteString;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.protobuf.ProtoCoder;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.TFRecordIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Create;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFn;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.ParDo;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;
import org.tensorflow.example.BytesList;
import org.tensorflow.example.Example;
import org.tensorflow.example.Feature;
import org.tensorflow.example.Features;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Sample {

    static class Foo extends DoFn<Map<String, String>, Example> {

        public static Feature stringToFeature(String value) {
            ByteString byteString = ByteString.copyFrom(value.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            BytesList bytesList = BytesList.newBuilder().addValue(byteString).build();
            return Feature.newBuilder().setBytesList(bytesList).build();
        }

        public void processElement(@Element Map<String, String> element, OutputReceiver<Example> receiver) {

            Features features = Features.newBuilder()
                    .putFeature("foo", stringToFeature(element.get("foo")))
                    .putFeature("bar", stringToFeature(element.get("bar")))
                    .build();

            Example example = Example
                    .newBuilder()
                    .setFeatures(features)
                    .build();

            receiver.output(example);
        }

    }

    private static Map<String, String> generateRecord() {
        String[] keys = {"foo", "bar"};
        return IntStream.range(0,keys.length)
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors
                        .toMap(i -> keys[i],
                                i -> RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(8)));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Map<String, String>> records = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            records.add(generateRecord());
        }

        System.out.println(records);
        Pipeline p = Pipeline.create();

        p.apply("Input creation", Create.of(records))
                .apply("Encode to Exampple", ParDo.of(new Foo())).setCoder(ProtoCoder.of(Example.class))
                .apply("Write to disk",
                        TFRecordIO.write()
                                .to("output")
                                .withNumShards(2)
                                .withSuffix(".tfrecord"));

        p.run();


    }
}
```

For the above code I am getting the following error at compile time

```
Error:(70, 17) java: no suitable method found for apply(java.lang.String,org.apache.beam.sdk.io.TFRecordIO.Write)
    method org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.<OutputT>apply(org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.PTransform<? super org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection<org.tensorflow.example.Example>,OutputT>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) OutputT
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.<OutputT>apply(java.lang.String,org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.PTransform<? super org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection<org.tensorflow.example.Example>,OutputT>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) OutputT
        (argument mismatch; org.apache.beam.sdk.io.TFRecordIO.Write cannot be converted to org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.PTransform<? super org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection<org.tensorflow.example.Example>,OutputT>))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

input to `TFRecordIO.write()` should be `byte[]` so making following changes worked for me.

```
static class Foo extends DoFn<Map<String, String>, byte[]> {

    public static Feature stringToFeature(String value) {
        ByteString byteString = ByteString.copyFrom(value.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        BytesList bytesList = BytesList.newBuilder().addValue(byteString).build();
        return Feature.newBuilder().setBytesList(bytesList).build();
    }

    public void processElement(@Element Map<String, String> element, OutputReceiver<byte[]> receiver) {

        Features features = Features.newBuilder()
                .putFeature("foo", stringToFeature(element.get("foo")))
                .putFeature("bar", stringToFeature(element.get("bar")))
                .build();

        Example example = Example
                .newBuilder()
                .setFeatures(features)
                .build();

        receiver.output(example.toByteArray());
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to convert the input to TFRecordIO to be byte[]

You can do it by using a transform like

```
static class StringToByteArray extends DoFn<String, byte[]> {
 @ProcessElement
 public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
  c.output(c.element().getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8));
 }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that a job of protcoder, which handles the serialisation  of protobuf messages

Comment: Coders do not change element type. They are only used for efficient coding and decoding of the element when elements are serialized and deserialized and type checking. If you check the documentation of TFRecordIO.Write, It takes a byte[] as input. For reference please check following documentation https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#data-encoding-and-type-safety  and https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.4.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TFRecordIO.Write.html#expand-org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection-

Comment: Great to know that it worked. Can you please accept the answer as it solves the problem in order to help the community.

Comment: @bruce_wayne, I kind of have a similar requirement , so I was trying to compile your code, but got compile time Error :  Error:(66, 82) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Class<org.tensorflow.example.Example> cannot be converted to org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder<byte[]>     Any  Idea on this ?

Comment: The return type of `processElement` should be bytes not the objects, check my answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/61367583/6082378 .